# plesk 9 spamassassin server wide blacklist via cron?

Tags: ubuntu, spam, spamassassin, blacklist

we're running ubuntu 8.04 LTS and plesk 9.2

our simple task is to set up a periodic black list for spamassassin, e.g. using this script ..

```
#!/bin/sh
#! Script by AJR to update local spamassassin rules
cd /tmp
wget -c http://www.stearns.org/sa-blacklist/sa-blacklist.current
mv sa-blacklist.current local.cf -f
mv local.cf /etc/mail/spamassassin -f
rm local.cf -f
/etc/init.d/psa-spamassassin restart
```

now, this script runs fine, but plesk doesn't seem to recognize the blacklist in its GUI.
which is annoying, especially because plesk itself writes to `/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf`. i wasn't able to find out the secret place, where plesk distinguishes between entries in `local.cf` added via GUI and command line.

any help is appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO spamassassin reads all *.cf files as config files in /etc/mail/spamassassin. So you could just download the blacklist as blacklist.cf in the /etc/mail/spamassassin folder and restart spamassassin.

I am not familar with plesk, so i dont if it helps in your situation.

also, I would suggest that you add some DNSBL checks (spamhaus, nix-spam) in front of your smtpd